# Default media uploader is not showing in wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

There is a custom post type events in the website. When I create a new post under events i am facing issue with media uploader

When i tried to upload the featured images in the english version of the website, it works properly.

But when i tried to upload the featured images in the arabic version of the website, the attached media uploader is shown.
[image]

How to get back the default wordpress media uploader?

Answer (score -1):

Fix the permissions issue for that uploads folder

Comment: Can you please explain?